# Threads exiting before joining

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, thread-synchronization

Forgive me I'm just beginning the concept of multi-threading, I was just wondering why my threads might be exiting before they're joined. Essentially, I am maintaining a global list of process id's, I create them iteratively by calling

```
   if(pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, function_to_execute, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error thread not created\n"); 
    }
```

Now the problem is, all my threads are exiting before they get to my pthread join

```
pthread_join(thread_id[i], NULL);
```

which is deeply nested in a function call, which is called directly after the threads are created. I'm not sure if I'm suppose to do some locking or something, or add an additional command to make sure the threads wait until the join statement before exiting.

Comment: It depends on `function_to_execute`. Maybe it throws an exception? And how can you tell that they are exiting before reaching `join`? Maybe they are in infinite loop or something

Comment: There is no problem if the thread you are `pthread_join()`ing with has already terminated. In this case, the `pthread_join()` will return immediately, while otherwise it must wait. *However*: You *must not* try to `pthread_join()` with a thread that has already been `pthread_join()`ed or `pthread_detach()`ed.

Comment: very good threading tutorial: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: thank you for all this info. @AhmadWabbi  I think you might be right regarding my problem, I have run some tests and limited the function to only printing "executed", and created the threads before a for loop, and joined on thread_id[i] after each iteration. Here is the output as follows: executed
executed
executed
looping..
looping..
looping..
looping..
executed

Comment: Since you're posing the question here, I suppose you've observed some kind of misbehavior that you construe in terms of your threads "exiting before they get to [your] pthread join."  As @EOF observes, a thread exiting before it is joined is not a problem, so unless your question is speculative, you've probably characterized it incorrectly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger right, ok that makes sense. The way I was interpreting it is that when I create each thread the thread is stored in the list of threads, and once join is called on a particular thread then it will run the function associated with it. This is bad logic right?

Comment: @noobatrilla, yes, your characterization is incorrect.  A new thread starts running (or at least is eligible to run) as soon as it is created.  The purpose of `pthread_join()` is to wait until the designated thread *finishes*, and to clean up after it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you sooo much, ok that makes sense. cheers

Answer (score 2):

From [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) documentation:

> The pthread_join() function shall suspend execution of the calling
>   thread until the target thread terminates, unless the target thread
>   has already terminated. On return from a successful pthread_join()
>   call with a non-NULL value_ptr argument, the value passed to
>   pthread_exit() by the terminating thread shall be made available in
>   the location referenced by value_ptr. When a pthread_join() returns
>   successfully, the target thread has been terminated. The results of
>   multiple simultaneous calls to pthread_join() specifying the same
>   target thread are undefined. If the thread calling pthread_join() is
>   canceled, then the target thread shall not be detached.

So, no. You don't need to take any additional measures as long as you satisfy the above requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why it would be a problem if threads are finishing before their exit status is claimed by `pthread_join()`?

This is perfectly normal.

`pthread_create()` starts new thread of execution at the specified function. The function runs immediately and may even preempt the starter thread. A thread has its own local variables (stack) and thread-local variables. All other shared memory accesses must be coordinated or data-racing will happen. Usually shared data is protected by mutexes. Thread will continue to run (usually parallel with other threads) until it is either blocked by some synchronization operation or thread exits the its start function.

The thread can wait with `pthread_join()` for other threads to finish execution successfully. Like [usr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39104765/1043152) noted pthread_join() won't wait if thread is already finished.